# LIKE statement to compare strings with hyphen

Tags: sql, string, ssms, sql-like

I am working in SQL and I have 3 columns Current Name, Given Full Name and Whether the names match (Y or No)

The problem with that is that when I am comparing the strings in the first 2 columns, it is not showing me the current result. For example, I am not finding a way to prove that 'Tushar Sharma' is same as 'Tushar-Sharma' considering that Tushar Sharma is the current full name and Tushar-Sharma is the name that has been extracted from a report.

I am stuck at the LIKE statement as to what to do if I want to have hyphen(-) included in the comparison so that I get a Y in the 3rd column.

Thank you

Comment: This is probably not something to be done by SQL, but by the data storage/fetching program. Please notice that how *you* consider two strings as equivalent is not obvious, you need to specify the rules for that. If you want "it sounds the same", look at SOUNDEX. If you only want some characters (no dash, no space, etc...) use a REGEX, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to remove the hyphen for the comparison:

```
select (case when replace(given_name, '-', '') = replace(full_name, '-', '') then 'Y' else 'N' end) as names_match
```

You can use `replace()` with `like` as well:

```
select (case when replace(given_name, '-', '') like '%' + replace(full_name, '-', '') '%' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as names_match
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it did not give the correct result. The 2 columns have around 10,000 names and I want to compare it using LIKE statement, but the only problem is the hyphen that is making it hard to compare and answer 'Y' in the 3rd column. Your code seems okay but is there a way that it can be done using a LIKE statement because there are certain names that are the same, for example John Smith is a very common name and therefore a LIKE statement for that will be great i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Replace - with whitespace and compare, you can also use regex or fuzzy matching to improve the match for other conditions.

```
AND REPLACE(CurrentName, '-', ' ') = REPLACE(GivenName, '-', ' ');
```

Ex:

```
AND REPLACE('Tushar Sharma', '-', ' ') = REPLACE('Tushar-Sharma', '-', ' ')
```

will eval to

```
AND 'Tushar Sharma' = 'Tushar Sharma'
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it did not give the correct result. The 2 columns have around 10,000 names and I want to compare it using LIKE statement, but the only problem is the hyphen that is making it hard to compare and answer 'Y' in the 3rd column. Your code seems okay but is there a way that it can be done using a LIKE statement because there are certain names that are the same, for example John Smith is a very common name and therefore a LIKE statement for that will be great i guess.

Comment: SQL Like probably is not what you think it is. Like usage is very limited. You probably should look at Regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select currentname,givenfullname,case when regexp_replace(currentname,' ','') like 
regexp_replace(givenfullname,' ','') the 'Y' else 'N' end as matchstatus from 
table_name;
```